# Virtuemart not sending new order "pending status" email

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

When i somebody create a new order that the status is pending, the virtuemart does not send the email order.

It sends just if the status is confirmed, or any others.

Someone know what can it be?

Answer (score 2):

Answer from https://forum.virtuemart.net/index.php?topic=126593.0

> The problem before was, that the email was sent twice. So we removed
>   sending emails for orderstatus Pending. Orderstatus Pending means that
>   the customer put something on the cashdesk, but did not pay or confirm
>   the order.

The only solution I've found and use:

In file
**components/com_virtuemart/helpers/shopfunctionsf.php**

ctrl+f to

`$orderstatusForShopperEmail = VmConfig::get('email_os_s',array('U','C','S','R','X'));`

On next line add

```
$orderstatusForShopperEmail[] = "P";
```

Answer (score 1):

In VirtueMart 3.4 it is again possible to receive an email for order status P, Pending, but only for the vendor.

The status "pending" is triggered once you hit the payment button and ends when the payment plugin sends a command to change the status into a new status like confirmed.
If in the time between these two processes something goes wrong the status will stay on pending.

For a successful payment the status should never be P "pending" even though it is possible to choose it in that way.

For payment methods that do not process the payment immediately like "invoice", meaning waiting for a payment via bank transfer or similar, status U "confirmed by shopper" should be used. It is often seen that in this case "Pending" is used, please don't do that.

Please rename "confirmed by shopper" into "my pending", so you got a status "pending" for stuck payments in the shop system, and a "my pending" for pending payments after a successful order process.

The latter status U will send emails to the vendor and shopper if you choose so in VM configuration, tab Orders (formerly called Email).